# C++ using *new class, lost pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

Curious as to why this fails. In the case where an object is returned rather than the pointer itself from using new, why is it illegal to make a pointer afterwards followed by deleting the pointer. Am I misunderstanding something with this sequence?

e.g.

```
Example e = *new Example();      //dereferencing the pointer to get Example object
Example* g = &e;                 //pointer pointing to e's address
delete g;                        //g is still pointer, but errors here.
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Your code exhibits UB because you try to delete an object that was not allocated with new.

Comment: `e` is a copy of the object you allocated using `new`. If you'd written `Example& e = ...`, your code would work. It would still be very weird code though ...

Comment: `*new` informally known as the memory leak operator ;)

Comment: @Charles - I would actually never do this, was just doing a small test and it looked legal to try out.

Comment: @Praetorian - from what you said I gather you mean to say the object on the heap is 'copied' to e which sits on the stack? so I could not call delete and basically lost my pointer and any way to free up the one on heap?

Comment: @lunyies correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ pointers don't work exactly like Java references. Let's break it down.

```
Example e = *new Example();
```

This line is constructing an `Example` object with dynamic storage duration, which is a fancy way of saying it's making an object *somewhere in memory*<sup>TM</sup>. You're then taking that object that exists *somewhere*<sup>TM</sup> and copying it into a value with automatic storage duration. Now you have an object that's *somewhere*<sup>TM</sup> and a separate, identical object that's stored on the call stack<sup>1</sup>. The former was allocated with `new`, and the latter was not.

```
Example* g = &e;
```

Now you're taking and declaring `g` as the address of `e`. But `e` is on the stack, so `g` points to an `Example` that was *not* allocated using `new`.

```
delete g;
```

Then you try to delete `g`, which points to an object with automatic storage duration. Hence, undefined behavior.

As @Rakete1111 mentioned in the comments, the behavior you're probably looking for is with C++ reference types.

```
Example& e = *new Example();
Example* g = &e;
delete g;
```

This will declare `e` as a *reference object*, so that it points to the original `Example` in dynamic storage while looking and acting like a C++ scalar otherwise. Then you can safely take the address of it and delete it, getting the desired behavior. However, this is incredibly unidiomatic and should probably not be used in real code.

---

<sup>1</sup> Strictly speaking, there's nothing in the C++ standard that says objects with automatic storage duration have to be on the call stack, but it can be helpful to think of it this way for didactic purposes.

Comment: How to fix it, use references: `Example& e = *new Example();` Not that I recommend this though.

Comment: Thank you - I didn't account for the copy constructor/assignment being invoked in this case.

Comment: You're a bit off here. The first instance is created _with_ dynamic storage _duration_ and the second with automatic storage duration.